# double checking if statement with is_file

Tags: php

does this look valid? I'm still writing the database coding for it but I want to make sure I'm on the right path so I won't have to many errors when I test.

```
$filechk1 = "../temp/files/" . $data[0] . ".doc";
$filechk2 = "../temp/files/" . $data[1] . ".doc";

if(is_file($filechk1) && is_file($filechk2)) {
        $rec_type = "3";
    } else if (!is_file($filechk1) && is_file($filechk2)) {
        $rec_type = "2";
    } else if (is_file($filechk1) && !is_file($filechk2)) {
        $rec_type = "1";
    }
```

Comment: IMHO your code is easier to understand than most of the proposals, you are just missing a check as @ajreal points out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$is_file_1 = is_file($filechk1);
$is_file_2 = is_file($filechk2);

if ($is_file_1) 
{
  $rec_type = $is_file_2 ? 3 : 1;
}
else
{
  if ($is_file_2) $rec_type = 2;
}
```

Looks like you forget to check if both file are in-valid..

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify it...

```
$filechk1 = "../temp/files/" . $data[0] . ".doc";
$filechk2 = "../temp/files/" . $data[1] . ".doc";

$rec_type = 0;
if(is_file($filechk1))
    $rec_type++; // $rec_type += 2;
if(is_file($filechk2))
    $rec_type += 2; // $rec_type++;
```

or

```
$filechk1 = "../temp/files/" . $data[0] . ".doc";
$filechk2 = "../temp/files/" . $data[1] . ".doc";

$rec_type = 0;
$rec_type += is_file($filechk1) ? 1 : 0;
$rec_type += is_file($filechk2) ? 2 : 0;
```

Also, if there is no file, `$rec_type` will be 0 (for both examples).

Comment: Both snippets give wrong result. The second is not even checking the second file at all.

Comment: @rik: First snippet works exactly as expected. You're right about the second, edited accordingly.

Comment: Poster wants !file1 && file2 => 2, file1 && !file2 => 1. Your code does !file1 && file2 => 1, file1 && !file2 => 2.

Comment: @rik, oh well, you get the point, don't you? I guess OP also knows how to change the values... But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$rec_type = 0;
if (is_file('../temp/files/'. $data[0] .'.doc'))
    $rec_type++;
if (is_file('../temp/files/'. $data[1] .'.doc'))
    $rec_type += 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just once more with type juggling

```
$rec_type = is_file('../temp/files/'. $data[0] .'.doc') * 1 // just to force an int
          + is_file('../temp/files/'. $data[1] .'.doc') * 2;
```